# What does Einstein's quote "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts" mean?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reality, physics, scientific-method

What did Einstein really mean by saying:

***If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts.***

Comment: You might be interested in the related question: [Modern responses to Popper's theory-laden observation](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3498/686)

Comment: The quote [can't be reliably attributed to Einstein](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Misattributed). Could you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Einstein recognized the human tendency of allowing pride to overrule honesty. When the facts prove that your theory is wrong, change the facts so you can continue to have the admiration of your peers and cronies, and in many cases to acquire the funds necessary to continue your work. Hats off to Einstein for his insight.